# Flask App crashing with elasticsearch query without error message

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

I have a flask app that is crashing without producing an error message every time it hits a very specific elasticsearch boolean query. The kicker is that the query is in a loop, and it doesn't crash every time it runs this query, on with certain query input. The only way this query differs is in the specific terms being searched for, the size, type, parameters, index, are all the same.

the query:

```
query = {
                "bool":{
                    "should": [
                            {"match": {"title": rawQuery}},
                            {"match": {"body": rawQuery}}
                        ],
                    "minimum_should_match": 1,
                    "must": {
                        "bool": {
                            "minimum_should_match": 1,
                            "should" : docIDs
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            
            ESres = self.es.search(
                    index = self.esDocIndex, 
                    request_timeout = 30,
                    body = {
                        'size': 10000,
                        'query': query,
            })
```

rawQuery is a string of search terms docIDs is a list (of 1000 items or less) of dictionaries of the following form:

```
{'term': {'id': docID}}
```

where docID is itself a string

using elasticsearch 7.3, python 3. The particular route using a get method, and involves quite a few elasticsearch queries but I can confidently say this is the only one that crashes it. I can provide more details about the flask app if necessary.

Comment: Hi, Its probably is because of the large number that you have set for your size. 10000 is a large amount of data and probably es couldn't response in 30 seconds. If you put the requested line in try except and also decrease this number, maybe your problem get solved.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the size limits the number of responses you can get. However as the search query terms being passed are at most 1000, and are unique docIDs in the index, the max number of returns is 1000, not actually 10000. Moreover, setting the request timeout to 60, even 120, did not solve them problem.